# Firebase: Using async/await syntax, how can I capture the firestore doc id?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

hopefully this isnt too hard to solve.

**TLDR;** Mostly the question is how to use `async/await` instead of `then()` syntax. More specifically how can I access docRef of the accessed document to return the `id` of that document along with all the other data?

---

I have a series of words objects that I retrieve from my firestore database.

Each of these words is an object that looks like this: `{word: 'Apple', ref: 9IOGPbdfoURivbNfffwF, points: 10}`

I iterate through each of these words to capture their full breakdown, provided at the destination of the `ref`. Each of these words, may or may not, include a `translations` sub-collection.

---

unfortunately, while I *can* successfully return `wordData`, that doc **does not** include the ID of the word. Rather, the ID I need is the ID of the word document itself. How can I write this so I have a `word` object that has all the word data + the ID of the doc using async/await syntax?

```
const data = Promise.all(
      vocab.map(async (word: Word) => {
        const wordRef = await word.ref.get();
        const wordData = await wordRef.data();     <-- Problem is here.
 
        const docRef = firebaseFirestore
          .collection(`languages/${language}/vocabulary`)
          .doc(wordData.id)                        <-- What i'm trying to do, but id isn't there
          .collection('translations')
          .doc(translationLanguage);
    ...
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data()` just returns the fields in the document.  It doesn't return the ID.  You already have the ID of the document in `word.ref`.

```
const id = word.ref.id;
```

Also, there is no need to use `await` with `data()`, since it doesn't return a promise.